# Sort and filter table rows on update

Tags: sorting, d3.js, filtering

I'm trying to update a table based on data that is changing over year. The problem is that I only want to show a subset of the data (10 items) and this is not working well together with the sort function. When I remove the filter function dynamically sorting by values works fine but all the data is displayed. With the filter function the sort function is not working and the first 10 items in alphabetical order are displayed. Any advice how to integrate the filter function correctly? Do I need to bind the data again via update, exit, remove?

Here is my code:

```
var rows_cotton = tbody_cotton.selectAll("tr")
      .data(all)
      .sort(function(a, b){ return d3.descending(parseInt(data_cotton_pc()[a.id]), parseInt(data_cotton_pc()[b.id])); })
      .enter()
      .append("tr")
      .filter(function(d,i) { return i < 10 })

    var cells_cotton_name = rows_cotton
      .append("td")
        .attr("class","column_name")
        .text(function(d,i){return nameById[d.id];})

    var cells_cotton_bar = rows_cotton
      .append("td")
      .attr("class","column_bar")
        .append("svg")
          .attr("width", 180)
          .attr("height", 5)
          .append("rect")
            .attr("height", 5)
            .attr("width", function(d) { return table_bars(parseFloat(data_cotton_pc()[d.id])); })
            .attr("fill","#BA3459")

    var cells_cotton_number = rows_cotton
      .append("td")
      .attr("class","column_number")
        .text(function(d,i){return data_cotton_pc()[d.id];})
```

and here is my update function:

```
      rows_cotton
      .sort(function(a, b){ return d3.descending(parseInt(data_cotton_pc()[a.id]), parseInt(data_cotton_pc()[b.id])); });

      cells_cotton_name
        .text(function(d,i){return nameById[d.id];})

      cells_cotton_bar
            .attr("width", function(d) { return table_bars(parseFloat(data_cotton_pc()[d.id])); })

      cells_cotton_number
        .text(function(d,i){return data_cotton_pc()[d.id];});
```

Comment: I would sort and filter the data before passing it to D3, not the selection.

Comment: I tried that. but then I still have the problem with the update function. In other years there are different items in the "top 10" list. When I filter the data before there are always the same 10 items just changing position and values because the others where filtered out at the beginning.